# C# Interfaces when used within method declaration

Tags: c#, interface

Quick question for you guys, I am trying to create an interface which defines a standard for factory functions when used in searching / viewing / creating / modifying records, so I created the following interface:

```
public interface iRecordAdmin
{
    iViewModel Create(iCreateModel model);
    iSearchResultsModel Search(iSearchModel model);
    void Hydrate(iRecordModel model);
    iViewModel Save(iRecordModel model);
}
```

I then have interface definitions for the individual model items to inherit (iCreateModel, iViewModel etc), but generally the interfaces contain no data specific properties, literally they are being used to ensure the factory classes follow a common pattern.

My problem comes when using these in the factories, when implementing the interface I can't use the implementing class in the method definition, for example:

```
public class CreateModel : iCreateModel
{
    /// ... propeties etc...
}
```

So in a class that inherits iRecordAdmin I try to use the class definition of CreateModel but the compiler rejects it saying the interface isn't implemented properly... So this doesn't work:

```
 public ViewModel Create(CreateModel model)
 {

 }
```

But this does:

```
 public iViewModel Create(iCreateModel model)
 {
     CreateModel newModel = (CreateModel)model;
 }
```

Now I understand that I can change the method parameter to that of the interface (iCreateModel in this case) but it's more useful to be able to use the class type to save casting from within the method.

Any ideas? Should I be designing this differently?

Comment: Sure you're not mistaking Interfaces for generics? Maybe `iViewModel Create<TViewModel>(TViewModel model) where TViewModel : iCreateModel`? _Side Note: What's with the `i`? You learn to program from Steve Jobs?_

Answer (score 3):

An interface defines a *contract*. By changing the parameter types in the implementation, you are violating that contract, and the call could easily fail from a class that is holding an interface reference.

Suppose a class had this code:

```
iRecordAdmin myAdmin = new CreateModel();
myAdmin.Create(new OtherCreateModel);
```

Clearly this code would fail given the parameter on `CreateModel` if this were allowed. Due to the interface definition, its perfectly valid and compilable code though.

You *could* use generics if that makes sense for your implementation, but only accepting a specific derived class when the interface takes a interface parameter is a bad idea, and not allowed in C#.That you are needing to cast like this certainly suggests that you need to re-think your design.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using explicit interface declarations.